# Getting data from Excel sheet

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I'm trying to write an Excel add-in using Microsoft Visual C# and VSTO. What I'm trying to do is read all of the data in the Excel sheet into a list of some sort so that I can process the list and write the list back to the sheet.

So far I have been unable to get any of the examples of the MSDN site to work.

- Environment  = Visual Studio 2010
- Language     = Visual C#
- Project type = Visual C# Excel 2007 Add-In

Answer (score 1):

You read/write the values from a `Range` variable into an `Array` using its `Value` property.  From there you can create a list or leave it as an array - your choice.

I will advise you NOT to read or write the 'Value' property of individual cells in a tight loop as you'll have a *significant* performance penalty.  Read the value into an array, modify the array, then write them back at one time.